# Export all files included in defconfig

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'd like to have directory tree containing only the files used by a specific Linux build.
For example if I use https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_moto_shamu with `make shamu_defconfig; make` that'd result in the Makefile system using the includes in the buildconfig to build.

Is there an (easy) way to have the Makefile system save the files it uses to a log, or most preferably to a different directory such that I'm left with a folder that contains only the files that're used for a build.

My goal is to be able to easily determine which code for the peripherals (e.g. touchscreen driver) is used.

Thanks

Comment: Use _make O=/path/to/output/dir ..._ as a first step. Also this https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, will try to go from there :).

Comment: Some info on streamline_config.pl https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/dcc60243e726978576cb02b74c84440629c69c87

Comment: Also this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470447/trying-to-find-all-the-kernel-modules-needed-for-my-machine-using-shell-script