# Print Kconfig Help for all enabled drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a kernel from a development kit that I am trying to clean up to eventually use for a production system. I want to remove as many drivers from the .config as possible, but I don't know what many of the drivers do. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the "help" field from the Kconfig files for each of the enabled drivers so I can better understand what the driver does.

I know I can go into each entry in menuconfig and press ? to get the "help", but we're talking hundreds of drivers, so this would be a very tedious process.

Comment: You can reduce configuration to what actually in use on the target device. Later I will try to find links about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to find all the kernel modules needed for my machine using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470447/trying-to-find-all-the-kernel-modules-needed-for-my-machine-using-shell-script)

Comment: I think @0andriy refers to `make localmodconfig` and it can save you a lot of boring work. Unfortunately I think it only works for Kconfig entries set to 'm' (modules), not those set to 'y' (built-in) so its usefulness would be limited if you have most drivers built-in.

Comment: @LucaCeresoli, not exactly. There's a script called _streamline_config.pl_, which does much better job. Follow the above link for the details.

Comment: @0andriy sorry, I didn't see your 2nd comment. thanks!

Comment: Since I'm building for an arm board I followed the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do) to get my .config from my board and my lsmod results. I tried to run `make LSMOD=/tmp/mylsmod localmodconfig` but it keeps trying to get me to select new config options. Probably because I don't have target set correctly, since I'm using yocto for my build. Unfortunately my yocto version doesn't have an option for localmodconfig. I tried the streamline_config.pl anyway and it just changed my =m to not set.
I will still need to remove modules.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your issue is to start from a preset mode such as `defconfig` and adding only the features you need.

This way, you will have a minimal kernel that will compile really fast.

Comment: We'll probably end up doing that once we get the our new board up and running and all our other components picked out, but we're still in the designing and testing phase of our new board, so most of the work is being done on the dev kit.

Answer (score 0):

This prints all Kconfig help:

```
find linux-4.14.47/drivers -name Kconfig -exec perl -ne 'print $_ if /menuconfig/ .. /^$/' {} \;
```

You can loop through .config in Perl and make a hash of enabled entries with:

```
$cfg{substr($_,7,-3)}=1 if /=[ym]$/;
```

With a little work you can mash these together

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try to use this with autoconf.h to print out the modules that are enabled.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to do it all in Perl.